# Self Extract ZIP?

Tags: python, vbscript, background, zip, self-extracting

I need help creating a self extracting zip file that does not display anything. I just need it to extract the files to a given place in the background. Everything I have found displays a dialog, but I need it to just run in the background.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't mind using a command line program, you can try here:

http://www.info-zip.org/UnZip.html

It's based on [ZLib](http://zlib.net/), a free (BSD-like) zip and unzip library.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using [7Zip](http://www.7-zip.org/). It can handle more than just zip format, has a command line making it easy to integrate with python or vb scripts.

Answer (score 0):

you can use python's [zipfile](http://docs.python.org/library/zipfile.html) module, and call extract or extractAll method with specified directory....